# avoiding column constrains NULL data

Tags: c#

I am trying to avoid formating null values while getting dates from my database 
but I am getting error message that says

> column constrains NULL data

I tried to use GetString instead of using GetValue at the else part but that's wont help me

```
if (!Convert.IsDBNull(oraReder[4]))                         //NEXT_INTEREST_DATE
{
    TBNextInterestDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(oraReder[4]).ToString("hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy");
}
else
{
    TBNextInterestDate.Text = oraReder.GetValue(4).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple, you need to control the field by the reader and not directly on the value.

```html
if (!oraReder.IsDBNull(4))                         //NEXT_INTEREST_DATE
{
    TBNextInterestDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(oraReder[4]).ToString("hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy");
}
else
{
    TBNextInterestDate.Text = oraReder.GetValue(4).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is

```
if (oraReder[4] != DBNull.Value)
{
    TBNextInterestDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(oraReder[4]).ToString("hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Comment: still getting same error message column constrains NULL data